# want to use session variable on login page

Tags: php, session

here is my file reg.php

```
class user
  { 
     var $name;
     var $email;
     var $password;
     function register()
     {
        $query ="SELECT id from user WHERE email ='$this->email' and password ='$this->password'";
        $data=mysql_query($query);
        $rec=mysql_fetch_array($data);
        if($rec)
        {
        echo $msg="Email Already Exit";
        }
        else
        {
        $query="insert into user(user_id,name,email,password)values('".$_SESSION['ID']."','$this->name','$this->email','$this->password')";

            if(mysql_query($query))
            {
            echo $msg="Student Succesfully Added";  
            }   
            else
            {
            return FALSE;
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

there are 5 fields in the data base name id, user_id,name,password,email..
i want to use this id in login.php page by using sessions...

Comment: Where is the code you putting the id in the session?

Comment: OK, so go ahead and do it. What's stopping you?

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: i want to display the content of user table on login page.. can you please suggest me where to get the value in this code so that i will be able to use that session variable in login page...

Answer (score 1):

Add `session_start();` at the start of all pages.

Set `$_SESSION['name'] = 'value'` on `reg.php`.

Use it like `$_SESSION['name']` on `login` page.

Comment: if($rec)
   {
    session_start();
   $_SESSION['ID']=$rec['id'];

Comment: session_start(); has to be at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `session_start();` at the start of all pages.

`Set $_SESSION['name'] = 'value'` on reg.php.

`Use it like $_SESSION['name']` and `$_SESSION['pw'] on login page.

where name is your username and pw your password

Comment: session_start(); starts the sesion and it's logical that it has to be on the top of every page.